# A safe way to add a key to map in Golang

Tags: dictionary, go

Due to this fact:

> If a map entry is created during iteration, that entry may be produced
>   during the iteration or may be skipped. The choice may vary for each
>   entry created and from one iteration to the next.

It's not safe to add key-values to map during iteration:

```
var m = make(map[string]int)
m["1"] = 1
m["2"] = 2
m["3"] = 3

for k, v := range m {
    if strings.EqualFold( "2", k){
        m["4"] = 4
    }
    fmt.Println(k, v)
}
```

Sometimes `"4"` key is produced, sometimes not.

What is the workaround to make it always produced?

Comment: The desired behavior is unclear. As in Go, ranging through a map is unordered, what if you have already visit `"4"` before? What do you expect? Please clearify this.

Comment: @leafbebop program guarantees that it always adds an unique value into the map. I just to  need to see it while iteration (no matter in which order).

Comment: Just remember to insert 4 and do it _after_ iterating through the map. So dead obvious that this cannot be the answer. Do you have any unmentioned constraints?

Comment: @Volker Actually yes. The real scheme is `map[pid]*Process`. And I send signals them via `chan` to start to do job while ranging. However, `Process` can create child process and child process also can do in own turn (not always). If `Process` created a child I also need to send `start` signal to child. Because I don't know the depth of "creating child process" I can't do it after *iterating*.

Comment: Well, maybe a map is not the right structure at all for something that sound awfully treeish.

Answer (score 6):

Create another map with the items you want to add to the original map, and after the iteration, you merge them.

```
var m = make(map[string]int)
m["1"] = 1 
m["2"] = 2 
m["3"] = 3 

var n = make(map[string]int)

for k := range m { 
    if strings.EqualFold("2", k) {
        n["4"] = 4 
    }   
}   

for k, v := range n { 
    m[k] = v 
}   

for _, v := range m { 
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```